# Why are internal class attribute variables not visible in aspx inline markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, scope

I am working on learning asp.net a little, and have found that the 'internal' keyword modified attribute members of a different class from the codebehind but in the same project as an aspx file are not visible from that aspx inline markup.  Is there a reason for that scoping separation?  Relatedly, assuming the server hosting the asp.net website code will be reasonably secured, is there a security risk with marking things like, as an example, database connection string credential literals with the public modifier?

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: see comment below, I supposwe it is good that markup inline code and compiled codebehind are not in the same assembly, securitively speaking

Answer (score 1):

`internal` means "visible within the same assembly". In ASP.NET, the markup and the codebehind may not be in the same assembly.

Comment: hey then, is there ever a situation the markup inline code and codebehind are in the same assembly?  some sort of more modern iis module core circumstance maybe?

Comment: No situation that I know of. There is a precompilation feature for web site "projects", but I don't know if it's possible to put the results into a single assembly; nor do I see the value in doing so. That certainly doesn't outweigh the disadvantages of web site "projects".